# Add avPlayer in Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

i'm facing problem with avplayer, my uitableview content videos list, that i need to auto play when cell fully visible, likewise in instagram. i have follow these 
example :[TableView Cell video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767717/tableview-cell-video-autoplay)

and 
[Play video on UITableViewCell when it is completely visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825994/play-video-on-uitableviewcell-when-it-is-completely-visible)

and video is playing fine in first cell but when i scroll up and down tableview. the avplayer are continually added and just buffering and not able to play  next video.

i have also follow the https://github.com/guilhermearaujo/GUIPlayerView and try to added in cell but facing same problem avplayer layer continually added and next video is not playing.

so, please help and suggest me some solution.

Thank you.

Comment: problem is cell reusability.

Comment: Thanks @ravi.p, you are right , problem has solve i have use this link ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786914/avplayer-on-left-side-of-cell-works-perfectly-avplayer-on-right-side-of-cell-do?rq=1